Zsh: Copy or Move symlinks to regular files, but not symlinks to directories (or vice versa)
In Zsh,

to copy regular files, I can use cp source-dir/*(.) dest-dir/
to copy directories: cp source-dir/*(/) dest-dir/
to copy everything else, e.g., symlinks, pipes, and devices:
cp source-dir/*(^./) dest-dir/

But how is it possible to copy, e.g., symlinks to regular files, but not symlinks directories? Or vice versa, symlinks to directories, but not symlinks to regular files?

Use the - qualifier for the following qualifiers to apply after symlink resolution, combined with @ (before the -!) to test for symlinks.
cp -- *(@-.)    /symlinks/to/regular/files/
cp -- *(@-/)    /symlinks/to/directories/
cp -- *(-@)     /broken/symlinks/
cp -- *(@-^./@) /all/other/symlinks/

From info zsh qualifiers (same online for the latest version of zsh):

-
toggles between making the qualifiers work on symbolic links (the default) and the files they point to, if any; any symbolic link for whose target the ‘stat’ system call fails¹ (whatever the cause of the failure) is treated as a file in its own right

Remember that if you enable completion (with compinit), you can get inline help about qualifiers by pressing Tab as usual, where you'll see:

$ echo *(Tab
[...]
f  -- + access rights
F  -- non-empty directories
-  -- follow symlinks toggle
G  -- owned by EGID
g  -- + owning group
[...]

It may also be worth noting that by symlink resolution here, we mean full symlink resolution. For instance, *(@-.) will also select a file that is a symlink to another file that is itself a symlink to a regular file (like with GNU find's -xtype f or with ['s -f). As seen above, *(@-@), same as -@ is not for symlinks to symlinks but for broken symlinks (same as GNU find's -xtype l), that is files which after full symlink resolution cannot be determined to be anything other than a symlink².
To check the type of the direct target of a symlink only, it would be more complicated, as you'd need to do one level of symlink resolution by hand³.
Could be something like:
zmodload zsh/stat
target_of_type() {
  local target mode
  stat -LA target +link -- $REPLY || return
  [[ $target = /* ]] || target=${${REPLY:h}%/}/$target
  stat -sLA mode +mode -- $target || return
  [[ $mode = $~1* ]]
}

Where you'd use *(@e[target_of_type X]) to select symlinks whose direct target is of type X, where X here is based on the first character of string representation of the mode (same as in the first field of the output of ls -l), so - for regular, d for directory, l for symlink etc:
cp -- *(@e[target_of_type -])          /direct/symlinks/to/regular/files/
cp -- *(@e[target_of_type d])          /direct/symlinks/to/directories/
cp -- *(@e[target_of_type l])          /direct/symlinks/to/symlinks/
cp -- *(@^e['target_of_type "*"'])     /symlinks/with/inaccessible/direct/targets/
cp -- *(@e['target_of_type "[^ld-]"']) /other/symlinks/


¹ Strictly speaking, that should rather be "any symbolic link for which the ‘stat’ system call fails", though that might have been less clear to casual readers. That is - toggles from using lstat() to using stat() on the same file, but if the stat() fails, the qualifiers apply based on the result of lstat() instead. Which is why -@ selects broken symlinks, but can also cause confusion, as for instance, *(-L+0), meant to return non-empty files after symlink resolution would also return broken symlinks whose target length is greater than 0, so any broken symlink since a symlink target cannot be an empty string. In any case, *(-.L+0) would probably be more appropriate in that case, regardless of that issue.
² For instance because the chain of links includes one to a file that doesn't exist or traverses a directory you don't have search permission for or there's a symlink loop...
³ As opposed to letting the system do that resolution. On Linux-based systems, for the case of the magic symlinks in /proc/*/fd, doing that resolution by hand can yield the wrong result as the advertised target path of those symlinks (as returned by the readlink() system call) doesn't necessarily refer to the file opened on the corresponding fd. That's the case in particular when the file has been deleted, where readlink() returns the original path with  (deleted) appended to it, while a stat() on it would manage to return information of the deleted file.

Since that's not a property of the symlink, but of the target of the symlink, there's no glob to do that.
So, you will have to write a for loop over all symlinks (for symlink in source-dir/*(@); do…), and in there, will have to use readlink "${symlink}" to get the target of the individual symlink, and then check [[ … ]] for the symlink pointing to a directory ([[ -d…) and otherwise (||) continue to the next symlink.

You don't need readlink as the -d test would resolve the link.

... you could avoid the explicit loop by using a shell code qualifier I think? ex. *(@e:'[[ ! -d $REPLY ]]':

@steeldriver didn' know that would work
